# Re-Register CF9 Enterprise License with Adobe

Tags: coldfusion

We are changing web servers but keeping CF9 Enterprise for a bit longer. Both the old and new servers will be online at the same time while we cut over. How long can we run like this before Adobe sends us a nasty-gram or revokes the license?

Comment: Why don't you ask Adobe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to the software vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe ColdFusion licenses don't "phone home" so they'll never know. As long as only one set of servers are active and taking production traffic at a time, you shouldn't be in violation of the EULA.  Disclaimer: This is my opinion. Ask @coldfusion on Twitter and you should get a quick (and official) response.

Comment: I marked this as correct for the suggestion of @coldfusion. Thanks  Brad.